# How to read default choice values in multiple choice Questions in Qualtrics platform

Tags: javascript, survey, qualtrics

I am trying to create a survey in Qualtrics and I need to get the hidden question default values once the survey is completed.

as of now i am getting NUll response when the question is hidden and even if i have selected default values for hidden questions.

Please check the sample survey here [https://qfreeaccountssjc1.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_01ZvjCb5OymyP09?Q_SurveyVersionID=current&Q_CHL=preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uss6g.png).

Survey Image:
[image: Survey Image]

I have set condition on choice 10 and 30 it will not hide question and if it is selected 20 then question 2 will be hidden in above test survey and it's responses are not catched under data and analysis tab .

Please refer this screenshot so i need to capture it's responses via javascript.

[image]

so anybody can please help me on that.

Comment: thanks leonardo-alves-machado for editing my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use the below Method to Do above.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/

     if("${q://QID1/SelectedChoicesRecode}"!="2") jQuery("#"+this.questionId).hide();

});
```